# Use local class library as resource for Web API (ASP.NET Core 1.0)

Tags: dll, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, class-library

I'm stuck with very simple problem.

I want to load local .NET 4 class library (dll) project to be used as resource in my new ASP.NET Web API project (first time trying asp.net)

I'm familiar with Winforms apps and now trying to create a ASP.NET Web API to be able to access one of my helper DLL from PHP/linux server. I'm not sure if this is a good approach, but I'm trying to prevent from re-implementing the logic of the DLL in PHP code.

The problem now is that I'm not able to add the DLL or the library class project to the resources of the Web API project.

While trying to solve the problem i have tried:

1. Visual Studio 2015 new project->ASP.NET web application->ASP.NET Core 1.0
   templates->Web API
2. Create new Class Library project to the Web API solution (or import existing project)
3. Add the project to Web API project references
4. Add using directive of class library namespace to controller
5. Try to build and it gets error:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WebApplication1.DNX Core 5.0

For me it it seems that it's trying to fetch the resource from nuget or something.

I hope some one can easily point me my mistake so I can continue to work with the actual work. (Or am I just miss using the Web API concept?)

project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassLibraryTest2": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try to add the library to your Solution with File > Existing project? And after that add a reference to it in your webapi project?

Comment: I have also tried that way first and failed same way. So I tried to rip of all other sources of error so i gave creating new library class project to web api and same reason used it as an example to the question.

Comment: Maybe you can setup a local NuGet feed, and install the reference via that nuget feed. Tutorial here: https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof I seem like overkill for getting one dll to your project resources, but i can try. Any how in the end I would like to be able to bring existing library class project to Web API solution and use it as resource. This is straight forward in WinForms but maybe it's not for Web API / asp.Net

Comment: Wait, I think I spotted your issue haha. Can you remove the dnxcore50 part? I overlooked it. That part means that it's trying to compile the library against the newest version of dnx, which fails if you rely on framework specific code.

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof thanks for suggestion. It seems that removing "dnxcore50": {} helps it to compile but removes all the DNX Core 5.0 references from the Web API project. Also even though the ClassLibraryTest2 resource is shown under DNX 4.5.1. references trying to use it in controller gives error "Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ClassLibraryTest2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" Maybe the  reference in project.json should be outside of DNX 4.5.1 and DNX core 50

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof Okay after changing the library target to .Net 4.5.1 the ClassLibrary resource is usable in controller. This is progress but not the perfect solution to referencing to the .Net 4 ClassLibrary. Also I don't understand if I'm losing some important references while ditching out the dnxcore50.

Comment: @Repeat Spacer the dnxcore50 stuff is still in RC status and final version has not been announced yet. So probably you can go without it for the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm first time playing with asp.net/webservices/web api, so I thought if i create new project from visual studio 2015 asp.net 5 templates it would be fine. Not sure if the problem is still me not understanding the concept how i should deliver dll functionalities (business logic) to .net 4 winforms and php app on linux server..

Comment: To get this work now I decided to use the previous version: I created empty project with Web API references from ASP.NET 4.5.2 project templates (in visual studio 2015). This way I'm able to add the reference to the project and then create simple API-controller to consume the library methods via REST.

Answer (score 2):

No need to remove the dnxcore50 part.

Just remove  `"ClassLibraryTest2": "1.0.0-*"` from dnx451 and add the dependency in the list of global dependencies. It will apply it on dnx451 and dnxcore50.

The project.json would look like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "ClassLibraryTest2": "1.0.0-*"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "dependencies": {            
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Moving dependency there gives me other error: "Error NU1002 The dependency ClassLibraryTest2 1.0.0 in project WebApplicationTest2 does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0." (the class library is now .NET 4 but I have tried higher versions too with same error)

Comment: I also tried to remove the "dnxcore50": {} from frameworks and it then builds but still when trying to use ClassLibrary in controller I get the error "Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ClassLibraryTest2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Now it's working if I remove the dnxcore50 and change the ClassLibrary target to .Net 4.5.1 it works and doesn't actually matter if the dependency is in dnx451 or in global dependencies. (But that way I cant use .Net 4 ClassLibrary and I lose dnxcore50 dependencies)